# PHP validate upload and convert files based on file type

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, upload, type-conversion

I have to following code to upload files with php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload your files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?PHP
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>
```

Its working, but fine my question is how to add/implement a **secure validation** based on file type and also convert files?

All images files should be converted to **jpg type** and all videos files should be converted to **mp4 type**.

In the upload process I also should add `randon()` name to the file.

**IMPORTANT:** after validation, all images should go to `upload/images/` and all videos to `upload/videos/`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a switch statement that determents the original file type, and then use multiple libraries to convert the original file type to the preferred file type.

```
switch ($originalfiletype){
case '.png':
//Process image through a .png to .jpg library
break;
case '.pdf':
//Process image through a .pdf to .jpg library
break;
case '.webm':
//Process video through .webm to .mp4 library
break;
default:
echo "Your file type is not supported";
break;
}
```

This process is very inconvenient and tedious, but unfortunately, there is no other way. PHP simply doesn't have a built-in library that converts every file type.

Comment: Ok, I will look into a library to convert

Comment: A good one for .jpg to .png would be this, https://github.com/WPPlugins/png-to-jpg/blob/master/png-to-jpg.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` to get the upload file type, but this may not accurate. You can use below code to get the file type.

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $temp_name);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Then you can check if `$mime_type` is in something like,

```
'image/jpeg' => FILE_TYPE_JPG,
'image/jpg' => FILE_TYPE_JPG,
'image/png' => FILE_TYPE_PNG,
'image/gif' => FILE_TYPE_GIF,
'video/mp4' => FILE_TYPE_MP4,
'video/webm' => FILE_TYPE_WEBM,
```

From the `mimetype` of the uploaded file,you can filter you wanted images and videos and drop unwanted files. Then move image and video to different directory.

To transfer video to  mp4 you can use `ffmpeg -i example.mov example.mp4`

To transfer image to jpg you can use `convert 0000.png 0000.jpg`

For a random name you can use `md5_file($file_name)` as file name.

Note, there may be more parameters for `ffmpeg` and imagemagick `convert` to adjust when you convert your videos and images.

Comment: everything looks good but not the random. This will no be really random, upload the same file twice and it will generate the same number. Some many ways to do this but here is one option `$r=bin2hex(random_bytes(10)).strtr(microtime(),['.'=>'',' '=>'']);` . Additional of the random chars also add time to avoid possible collision.

Comment: where are `convert` or `ffmpeg` in php? do I need to install something  ?

Comment: @OtávioBarreto You can test on your server with `ffmpeg -version` and `convert -V` to check if your server has installed them by default. If not, you have to install it yourself. For installation, you can google `ffmpeg` and `Imagemagick`(convert).